# AngularJS custom datepicker directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, directive

I would like to make a custom datepicker directive with a custom template.

But I have no idea how to start building it...

How to include date data for my directive?

I appreciate your guide or give me some advice to work on this more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

It might help you! follow the below steps

HTML code sample:

```
    <label>Birth Date</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="birthDate" date-options="dateOptions" custom-datepicker/>

<hr/>

<pre>birthDate = {{birthDate}}</pre>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom-datepicker.html">
    <div class="enhanced-datepicker">
        <div class="proxied-field-wrap">
            <input type="text" ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd" ng-model="ngModel" ui-date="dateOptions"/>
        </div>
        <label>
            <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
            <span class="datepicker-date">{{ngModel | date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS code sample:

```
    angular
    .module('App',['ui.date'])
    .directive('customDatepicker',function($compile){
        return {
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'custom-datepicker.html',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                dateOptions: '='
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller){
                var $button = $element.find('button');
                var $input = $element.find('input');
                $button.on('click',function(){
                    if($input.is(':focus')){
                        $input.trigger('blur');
                    } else {
                        $input.trigger('focus');
                    }
                });
            }    
        };
    })
    .controller('myController',function($scope){
        $scope.birthDate = '2013-07-23';
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            minDate: -20,
            maxDate: "+1M +10D"
        };
    });

/*global angular */
/*
 jQuery UI Datepicker plugin wrapper

 @note If ≤ IE8 make sure you have a polyfill for Date.toISOString()
 @param [ui-date] {object} Options to pass to $.fn.datepicker() merged onto uiDateConfig
 */

angular.module('ui.date', [])

.constant('uiDateConfig', {})

.directive('uiDate', ['uiDateConfig', '$timeout', function (uiDateConfig, $timeout) {
  'use strict';
  var options;
  options = {};
  angular.extend(options, uiDateConfig);
  return {
    require:'?ngModel',
    link:function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      var getOptions = function () {
        return angular.extend({}, uiDateConfig, scope.$eval(attrs.uiDate));
      };
      var initDateWidget = function () {
        var showing = false;
        var opts = getOptions();

        // If we have a controller (i.e. ngModelController) then wire it up
        if (controller) {

          // Set the view value in a $apply block when users selects
          // (calling directive user's function too if provided)
          var _onSelect = opts.onSelect || angular.noop;
          opts.onSelect = function (value, picker) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              showing = true;
              controller.$setViewValue(element.datepicker("getDate"));
              _onSelect(value, picker);
              element.blur();
            });
          };
          opts.beforeShow = function() {
            showing = true;
          };
          opts.onClose = function(value, picker) {
            showing = false;
          };
          element.on('blur', function() {
            if ( !showing ) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                element.datepicker("setDate", element.datepicker("getDate"));
                controller.$setViewValue(element.datepicker("getDate"));
              });
            }
          });

          // Update the date picker when the model changes
          controller.$render = function () {
            var date = controller.$viewValue;
            if ( angular.isDefined(date) && date !== null && !angular.isDate(date) ) {
              throw new Error('ng-Model value must be a Date object - currently it is a ' + typeof date + ' - use ui-date-format to convert it from a string');
            }
            element.datepicker("setDate", date);
          };
        }
        // If we don't destroy the old one it doesn't update properly when the config changes
        element.datepicker('destroy');
        // Create the new datepicker widget
        element.datepicker(opts);
        if ( controller ) {
          // Force a render to override whatever is in the input text box
          controller.$render();
        }
      };
      // Watch for changes to the directives options
      scope.$watch(getOptions, initDateWidget, true);
    }
  };
}
])

.constant('uiDateFormatConfig', '')

.directive('uiDateFormat', ['uiDateFormatConfig', function(uiDateFormatConfig) {
  var directive = {
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var dateFormat = attrs.uiDateFormat || uiDateFormatConfig;
      if ( dateFormat ) {
        // Use the datepicker with the attribute value as the dateFormat string to convert to and from a string
        modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          if (angular.isString(value) ) {
            return jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, value);
          }
          return null;
        });
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
          if (value) {
            return jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, value);
          }
          return null;
        });
      } else {
        // Default to ISO formatting
        modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          if (angular.isString(value) ) {
            return new Date(value);
          }
          return null;
        });
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
          if (value) {
            return value.toISOString();
          }
          return null;
        });
      }
    }
  };
  return directive;
}]);
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but I am still wondering how to make the datepicker layout by myself. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I think it might help you!! go to https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&q=how+to+create+datepicker+layout+in+angularjs&spell=1&sa=X&ei=MeAbVYitA8eF8gXH4YCABQ&ved=0CBoQBSgA&biw=1366&bih=643

Comment: [Possible jQuery UI Datepicker source code source](https://github.com/bdb-opensource/ui-date/blob/4810384f1846d3a10275d28faa8d05c7d1ab9f26/src/date.js).